# Wpf usercontrol lost focus event or muse down beyond my control

Tags: c#, wpf, events

do you know a "simple" way to detect when a user control loses focus?
I am creating a console output inspired by Visual Studio.
Visual Studio console output collapses when I click anywhere.
Obviously in my application if I click on a Panel (which has no focus) I do not receive any events.
I had thought about using the mouse_down event on the application, but I would have to do an evaluation with every click!
Do you know any way to know when you click out of your control?

Answer (score 0):

UserControl has a LostFocus event. In the code behind of your UserControl you can simply add an event handler.

```
public partial class MainView : UserControl
{
    public MainView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LostFocus += OnFocusLost;
    }

    private void OnFocusLost(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Do something here.
    }
}
```

If you are referencing it from another class then you can create an event handler on that class and subscribe to the event from the UserControl.

```
UserControl control = new UserControl();
control.LostFocus += OnFocusLost;
```

With that being said, if you have a TextBox or some other control inside of the UserControl then the UserControl will lose focus every time a TextBox gets the focus so you will most likely need to write a method to determine if any of the elements inside the UserControl have focus.